# Cleanly generating several 0-airty JavaScript functions with slightly different bodies

Tags: javascript, functions

Say I have a bunch of JavaScript functions similar to:

```
message = [“000”, “111”, “222”, “333”];

function F0(){
    alert (message[0]);
}

function F1(){
    alert (message[1]);
}

function F2(){
    alert (message[2]);
}

function F3(){
    alert (message[3]);
}
```

Is there a way to make some kind of template for this set of functions?

That is, to declare something like:

```
function F<T>(){
   alert (message[T]);
}
```

The reason is quite simple. In my solution, I have much more complex functions performing the same action (they are callback functions for a few XMLHttpRequest objects). Each time I make a change, it needs to be reflected across all functions – something I’m looking to avoid. From within the function, I cannot know whether it was called by `XMLHttpRequest[5]` or  `XMLHttpRequest[2]`, therefore I created a few similar functions (for each  XMLHttpRequest object). I’m looking for a way to prototype those functions, so I’ll keep the logic in one place. So far, I haven’t found a way to achieve that with JavaScript.

Just to be clear, I'm using those functions for `XmlHttpRequest.onstatechange` so those are called *without any parameters* (something like: `xhr[0].onstatechange = F0; xhr[1].onstatechange = F1;`). I'm looking for a way to prototype just the function and than create a few "instances" of it, differentiated by an index within those function themselves.

Comment: Note that JScript is a Microsoft-specific JavaScript variant, but is not the same as JavaScript. I answered assuming you really meant JavaScript.

Comment: Yes, that right.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, use function arguments:

```
function F(T) { alert(message[T]); }
```

If you need a function that given this “template” can subsequently be invoked without arguments, we can use a *closure* – returning a function from within a function:

```
function makeF(T) {
  return function F() { alert(message[T]); };
}

// var F1 = makeF(1);
// etc.
```

The C++ templates or Java/C# generics are like compile-time functions which are mostly used for creating a family of types. JavaScript doesn't really have a compile-time type system, or even a compile time, so those concepts don't apply here. We can therefore supply arguments at run time to pretty much the same effect.

Comment: First, hello amon and thank you. Second, I'm using those functions for XmlHttpRequest.onstatechange so those are called *without*  parameters (something  like: xhr[0].onstatechange=F0;  xhr[1].onstatechange=F1;) so unfortunately, it doesn't fit. I'm looking for a way to prototype just the function and than  create a few "instances" of it, differentiated by an index *within* those function themselves.

Comment: @Alex ah, that makes sense. See update.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is function.bind which will return a function with the arguments bound to it:

`var f1 = F.bind(null, 1)`

See - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind